# which approach is good to for assert

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mstest, assert

**First Approach** :  Using try-catch block as well as Asset.Fail too.

I am using this technique to print few messages in loggers before and after execution starts

```
[TestMethod]
public void abcButton()
    {
want to print messages so many Logger signs are here

                Utility.Logger.Write("** " + string.Format(" {0} - {1}", GetType().Name, MethodName) + " Test Case is started  *****");
    Utility.Logger.Write("***********************");
    try
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(LoginPage.CheckBtn());
        Utility.Logger.Write("********************");
        Utility.Logger.Write("***** " + string.Format(" {0} - {1}", GetType().Name, MethodName) + " Test Case is Passed  *****");
        Utility.Logger.Write("******************************************************");
    }
    catch
    {
        Utility.Logger.Write("*************************");
        Utility.Logger.Write("***** " + string.Format(" {0} - {1}", GetType().Name, MethodName) + " Test Case is Failed  *****");
        Utility.Logger.Write("*********************");
        Assert.Fail();
    }

}
```

**OR** 
**Second Approach** : Using if-else condition, involved one more extra var 
I just want to see if there is a short approach can get from experts

```
[TestMethod]

public void abcButton()
{

    Utility.Logger.Write("** " + string.Format(" {0} - {1}", GetType().Name, MethodName) + " Test Case is started  *****");
    Utility.Logger.Write("***********************");
    var val = LoginPage.CheckBtn() ;
    if(val)){
        Assert.IsTrue(val);
        Utility.Logger.Write("********************");
        Utility.Logger.Write("***** " + string.Format(" {0} - {1}", GetType().Name, MethodName) + " Test Case is Passed  *****");
        Utility.Logger.Write("**************************************");
    }
    else
    {
        Utility.Logger.Write("*************************");
        Utility.Logger.Write("***** " + string.Format(" {0} - {1}", GetType().Name, MethodName) + " Test Case is Failed  *****");
        Utility.Logger.Write("*********************");
    }
}
```

Please let me know if we can handle such scenario in less code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the tests like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void abcButtonTest()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(LoginPage.CheckBtn(), "Checking return value");
}
```

Basic example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(false, "Assert failed");
}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, but when it fails then how you are going to print the fail message ? Utility.Logger.Write("********************fail");

Comment: MS Test uses the 2nd parameter as part of the failure message.

Comment: agree, but I want to log same in separate logging txt file. How we are going to send the  fail message. Please go through above my code. thanks for you reply. I have also thought to handle in Driver.close method but again I need to return which is not a good solution as of now.

Comment: That's my question is if you use just Assert then how you are going to write it in Log text file.

Comment: @MikeASP The question is... why are you logging everything twice?

Comment: @JeffC..No , I am not. Utility.Logger.Write("***); I am logging single time in my text file.